# Проверка файла на пустоту

Tags: python

Как проверить пуст ли txt файл?

Просто пытаюсь пустой открытый txt файл в print вывести - вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2507871/5741205

Comment: А что должно выйти в принт, если файл пустой?

Comment: Если файл пустой, то ничего печататься и не должно, потому что файл - пустой. Нечему там печататься.

Answer (score 1):

Размер файла в байтах возвращает [`os.path.getsize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize). Это не работает для директорий, именованных каналов, других специальных файлов.

Если вы хотите узнать, вернёт ли `.read()` метод какие-либо данные, то лучший способ, вызвать `.read()` когда вам эти данные нужны. Иначе, даже для регулярных файлов, между моментом когда вы `os.path.getsize()` вызвали и чтением файла с помощью `.read()`, его содержимое может измениться.